Did Kitaev prove the QMA-completeness of the Local Hamiltonian problem while on a flight to Chicago?
I believe the first publication of the proof of the QMA-completeness of the Local Hamiltonian Problem is as portions of a chapter in the book Classical and Quantum Computation, by Kitaev, Shen, and Vyilyi, published in Russian in 1999 (with an English translation later in 2003). Up until the book publication, the research papers that referenced the QMA-completeness of the LHP had cited a talk by Kitaev and titled "Quantum NP", at the second QIP/AQIP conference hosted by DePaul University in Chicago in January 1999.  The agenda for the conference is still available on the web, and looking at the presenters and the abstracts of their presentation gives me shivers.
I have heard a rumor that Kitaev had worked out the details of the problem and the proof of its QMA-completeness while flying to Chicago.  The story I had heard was that the conference encouraged presenters to discuss something novel, and Kitaev started thinking about the Cook-Levin theorem and wondering how to port it over to quantum computing. If so, to me it's a pretty fascinating anecdote, that such a foundational theorem was cobbled together on a flight in preparation for a talk about quantum computing, only four and a half years after Shor '94. I can imagine a pre-9/11, four-hour airplane flight from the west coast of the US to O'Hare Airport, with a handsome young Russian gentleman scribbling away on theoretical computer science and the limits it can teach us about quantum mechanics and the physical world itself.
But is there any source or other evidence to the story about the airplane flight, or am I confusing and exaggerating things? Given that the presentation at DePaul was probably the first enabling disclosure of the proof, was it worked out on the airplane as almost a last-minute afterthought?

I've never heard of this rumor until now and I cannot find any other source that mentions it either. In any case, Kitaev is the only one who can give possibly you a conclusive answer, so maybe try emailing him. :-)

Thanks! I’m too intimidated for that right now but I will try to dig up my source- maybe a presentation from D. Aharanov or S. Irani…

That too is quite fantastic although maybe expected of Kitaev. Especially if was already familiar with the topics. In any case, I would love to see it written as an answer. :-)

No.
Kitaev did not prove the QMA-completeness of LHP on a flight to Chicago in early 1999. He did so a couple of days before he flew from Russia to Israel in 1998.
In particular, around then D. Aharanov had heard of the works of Kitaev, then in Russia, and suggested he travel and meet with her and her advisor A. Wigderson in Israel (at Hebrew University.)  Wigderson agreed and Aharanov extended the invitation to Kitaev. Kitaev, being a physicist, wanted to be able to converse about theoretical computer science with Wigderson and Aharanov, and this is when he began to port Cook-Levin over to quantum computing - ~two days before his flight.

Aharanov explains this better than I ever could, at least a couple of times in some of her lectures about quantum computing and the limits it can teach us about physical reality.  See, here at about the 36-minute mark, and also here at about the 27-minute mark.
It sounds like I got it wrong in my time (in '98, not in '99), location (Israel, not Chicago), and level of spontaneity (two days before a flight, not during a flight itself). But the motivations were clear - a physicist hoped to talk shop with a bunch of theoretical computer scientists to speak their language.

Aharanov and Naveh's "Quantum NP - A Survey" also refers to a lecture Kitaev gave at Hebrew University, but mentions the date as '99 and not '98.

Here's a disconnected piece to add to this story. I went to visit Peter Shor when I was a graduate student, I believe in late 1996. The basic idea of QMA was already in the air and on the arXiv (E. Knill quant-ph/9610012), and we discussed it. I don't have a perfect memory of it, but I'm pretty sure that Peter suggested, as a research problem, proving that the local Hamiltonian problem is QMA-complete (although not necessarily using exactly those terms). I didn't understand the importance of Hamiltonians and didn't think about the problem again until Kitaev's AQIP'99 talk.

Wow! Awesome! Thank you so much for this story! I knew Kitaev referred to the "BQNP" completeness and only after your Succinct Quantum Proofs/group non-isomorphism paper did everyone agree that "QMA" is a much better name for the class, but I didn't know that even back in the mid-90's the idea of completeness of LHP was 'in the air', so to speak.

BQNP is a fine name for this complexity class, but I didn't like it for a ridiculous reason: the classical version of BQNP should be BPNP, but that refers to the BP operator applied to NP, which equals AM not MA. So why not call it QMA instead because MA is the right classical analogue? When I wrote a paper about the class a couple of years later, I used my preferred name QMA and it actually stuck.

I also thought the version of the class with a classical proof should be called MQA, because now it's just Arthur that's quantum and it kind of fits with the whole Arthur-Merlin naming convention. I didn't have anything interesting to say about MQA, though, so I never had a chance to use that name. Then Dorit named this class QCMA, which also stuck — and although I tried I wasn't able to repeat my success in renaming BQNP to QMA.

*group non-membership not group non-isomorphism
